# How to add close button in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I've this code:

```
...
MenuBar options = new MenuBar(true);
options.addItem("First Label", new ScheduledCommand()
        {
        @Override
            public void execute() {

            PopupPanel popupProperties = new PopupPanel();
            TabPanel tabPanel = new TabPanel();
            FlowPanel flowpanel = new FlowPanel();
            ...
            flowPanel.add(...);
            scroll = new ScrollPanel(flowPanel); 
            tabPanel.add(scroll, "First Tab");
            popupProperties.add(tabPanel);

            RootPanel.get().add(popupProperties);
            popupProperties.center();
            popupProperties.show();
            }
        }
...
```

If I add SimplePanel with Button (close) to popupProperties, it doesn't work. How can I do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: _"It doesn't work"_ What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Also your sample code does not contain how you add the `SimplePanel` and the `Button`. Please also post those.

Comment: In a SimplePanel you can add just one widget.

Comment: It doesn't work means that the popup panel does not show @Baz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a VerticalPanel and add it to the popup-panel. Add the TabPanel and the Button to the VerticalPanel.

And don't add the popup-panel to any panel. Use always center() to show it.